# Performing simultaneous unrelated queries in EF4 without a stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a page that pulls together aggregate data from two different tables. I would like to perform these queries in parallel to reduce the latency without having to introduce a stored procedure that would do both.

For example, I currently have this:

```
ViewBag.TotalUsers = DB.Users.Count();
ViewBag.TotalPosts = DB.Posts.Count();
// Page displays both values but has two trips to the DB server
```

I'd like something akin to:

```
var info = DB.Select(db => new { 
   TotalUsers = db.Users.Count(), 
   TotalPosts = db.Posts.Count());
// Page displays both values using one trip to DB server.
```

that would generate a query like this

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users) AS TotalUsers, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts) AS TotalPosts
```

**Thus, I'm looking for a single query to hit the DB server. I'm not asking how to parallelize two separate queries using Tasks or Threads**

Obviously I could create a stored procedure that got back both values in a single trip, but I'd like to avoid that if possible as it's easier to add additional stats purely in code rather than having to keep refreshing the DB import.

Am I missing something? Is there a nice pattern in EF to say that you'd like several disparate values that can all be fetched in parallel?

Comment: i'm guessing posts are not related to users?

Comment: Right. I just made up those two table names. My actual entities are something else that aren't related

Comment: I realise that this doesn't really help you, but I thought it was worth noting that NHibernate has a concept called 'Futures' which does kind of the same thing ( ie multiple queries in one request).

Comment: @StankK Thanks. This helpful in Googling to find the idea of MultiQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's no good way to do this (yet) in EF4. You can either:

1. Use the technique described by adrift which will generate a slightly awkward query.
2. Use the [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) where T is some dummy class that you create with property getters/setters matching the name of the columns from the query. The disadvantage of this approach is that you can't directly use your entity model and have to resort to SQL. In addition, you have to create these dummy entities.
3. Use the a [MultiQuery class that combines several queries into one](http://blog.cincura.net/232079-multiquery-more-queries-in-one-batch-in-entity-framework-using-linq/). This is similar to NHibernate's futures hinted at by StanK in the comments. This is a little hack-ish and it doesn't seem to support scalar valued queries (yet).

Answer (score 1):

This will return the counts using a single `select` statement, but there is an important caveat.  You'll notice that the EF-generated `sql` uses `cross join`s, so there must be a table (not necessarily one of the ones you are counting), that is guaranteed to have rows in it, otherwise the query will return no results.  This isn't an ideal solution, but I don't know that it's possible to generate the `sql` in your example since it doesn't have a `from` clause in the outer query.

The following code counts records in the `Addresses` and `People` tables in the Adventure Works database, and relies on `StateProvinces` to have at least 1 record:

```
var r = from x in StateProvinces.Top("1")
        let ac = Addresses.Count()
        let pc = People.Count()
        select new { AddressCount = ac, PeopleCount = pc };
```

and this is the SQL that is produced:

```
SELECT 
      1 AS [C1], 
      [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
      [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C3]
FROM    
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) [c].[StateProvinceID] AS [StateProvinceID] 
        FROM [Person].[StateProvince] AS [c] 
    ) AS [Limit1]
CROSS JOIN  
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1] 
        FROM [Person].[Address] AS [Extent2] 
    ) AS [GroupBy1]
CROSS JOIN  
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1] 
        FROM [Person].[Person] AS [Extent3] 
    ) AS [GroupBy2]
```

and the results from the query when it's run in SSMS:

```
C1          C2          C3
----------- ----------- -----------
1           19614       19972
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had been able to get something similar (in my case using a table that we have that has a single column and row with the current DB schema version in it). It too did the cross join. I'm starting to think that there's no good solution to this problem outside of creating a stored procedure. The problem with that approach is that I'd almost have to create a sproc for several of my views/pages to reduce latency. I also tried the DB.ExecuteStoredQuery but couldn't get it to work without creating a custom entity.

Comment: @Jeff Moser, if the alternative is that you'd have to create several stored procedures, then I would consider using this method, especially since you do have a table you can use that will have a record in it.  Since you are cross joining subqueries that each have only 1 row, I don't think performance of the cross joins will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish what you want with Parallel LINQ (PLINQ).  You can find an introduction [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx).

Comment: I'm familiar with PLINQ, but that approach isn't as optimal as I'd like. I'd rather have EF rewrite my request as a single query. I've updated my question to reflect this.